# Is the "current" status of a document equal to change.before.data() or change.after.data() when observing a Firestore document onUpdate event

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a situation where a user can have zero, one, or multiple subscriptions. The user should be deemed "subscribed" if he has at least one subscription with `status == "active"`.

I'm using the `onUpdate()` trigger to observe when a subscription changes. Then I get the user and check all of their subscriptions and set the user's `is_subscribed` attribute accordingly.

My logic only works under the assumption that the subscription being changed has already been updated in the user's `subscriptions` collection. But perhaps this isn't guaranteed? I couldn't find this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the term "current" here is confusing. `change.before` is the state of the database before the new change. `change.after` is the state of the database after the new change.

However, by the time the Cloud Function is executed, the change has already been committed to the database as Cloud Firestore Cloud Functions are not blocking Cloud Functions. Additionally, if you make multiple changes to the same document in quick succession, the `change.after` may not reflect the state of the document at the exact time the function is executing.

This means neither is the "current" version, as each is just a snapshot of the data before and after that particular change. In general, your Cloud Function should act only on the data that changed and nothing else as this will prevent confusing updates and help track the source of bugs when you have to review the logs.

In the logs for your function, you should log messages similar to "User #{uid} subscription to #{subId} was marked inactive" or "User #{uid} subscribed to #{subId}" and then make the relevant updates to the relevant documents.

If you require exactly what is in the database at the time of execution, use `getDoc(change.after.ref)` and then make use of the returned data. As mentioned before, be warned that this may lead to data conflicts and confusing behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. I'll paraphrase your writeup by saying "When the onUpdate function runs, the _current_ state the changed document in the database could be either `change.before` or `change.after` or possibly something else entirely." This is helpful, but do you have a reference for this?

Comment: What I've stated here is covered by the [Cloud Firestore Cloud Functions documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events). If you are going to paraphrase, you need to figure out what you mean by "current" as it's too ambiguous. You can interpret "current" to mean "What did the current data look like when this new data was written?" or "What data is currently in the database right now?". This is why they use the terms "before" (what was the data before this change?) and "after" (what does the data now look like?). In 90% of cases, you are probably looking for "after".